# Segmentation fault error in C program while using recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

Hi I have an array of type pair (which holds two integers winner and loser).Here there is a chance that loser might be a winner in another pair. One loser might have more than one pair where loser is a winner. I need to find if there is any such case where this chain of winner and loser pairs form a cycle or loop. If there is no such loop I want to update the two dimensional array locked for such pair as true or false, but I'm facing a segmentation error and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX 5

int preferences[MAX][MAX] = {0};

bool locked[MAX][MAX];

bool visited[MAX][MAX];

typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

pair pairs[] ={{0,2}, {0,1}, {0,3}, {1,2}, {0,4}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {4,1}, {4,2}};
int pair_count = MAX*(MAX - 1)/2;

void clear_workspace(void);
bool check_for_loop(int start, int end);
bool branches(int loser, int arr[]);
void lock_pairs(void);

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    lock_pairs();
}
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < pair_count;i++)
    {
        int start = pairs[i].winner;
        int end = pairs[i].loser;
        clear_workspace();
        if(check_for_loop(start, end) == false)
        {
            locked[start][end] = true;
        }
    }
}
bool check_for_loop(int start, int end)
{
    visited[start][end] = true;
    //branches(end);
    int arr[MAX * MAX] = {-1};
    if (branches(end,arr) == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < MAX;i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] != -1 && visited[end][arr[i]] == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (arr[i] != -1 && check_for_loop(start, arr[i]) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool branches(int loser, int arr[])
{
    int arr_index;
    arr_index = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < pair_count;i++)
    {
        if (pairs[i].winner == loser)
        {
            arr[arr_index] = pairs[i].winner;
            arr_index++;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = arr_index;i < MAX;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = -1;
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
void clear_workspace(void)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < MAX;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < MAX;j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the initialising variable at global and local scopes and also changing the conditions
I want the locked array to be true for pairs which doe snot make a loop
I am new to C programming and stack overflow sorry if I'm missing anything ...

Comment: Segmentation fault is a pointer error. Somewhere in your program (use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to find where) you use an invalid pointer.

Comment: By the way, why `int pair_count = MAX*(MAX - 1)/2;` instead of e.g. `int pair_count = sizeof(pairs) / siizeof(pairs[0]);`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There are no pointers in the program. So it's probably out of bounds array access.

Comment: An argument declaration like `int arr[]` is really `int *arr`. So yes there are pointers in your program. If the error is here I don't know. It could be just a plain stack overflow (because too deep recursion).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since it never assigns to them, they can't become invalid. They're just the array->pointer decay of the array argument.

Comment: Another common cause of segmentation fault is stack overflow. Make sure the recursion is reaching the base case.

Comment: You can still go out of bounds. Remember that for any array `arr` and index `arr_index` the expression `arr[arr_index]` is exactly equal to `*(arr + arr_index)`. Which means that `arr + arr_index`, which is a pointer, could become invalid. But like I said, I don't know if that's the case here. You ***really*** need to use a debugger to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When I used debugger it showed the error occurred at (branches(end,arr) == true )

Comment: And when you check the call-stack, how many invocations of `check_for_loop` are there? If it's a *lot* then your recursion is too deep.

Comment: The problem with too deep recursion is that compilers typically puts local variables, and sometimes arguments, on the stack. Then when a function is called the CPU itself puts some information on the stack. And the stack is a limited resource. On Windows the default stack for a process is usually only one single megabyte (for example, on Linux it's usually 8 MiB). If the recursion becomes too deep you get more and more on the stack, until it runs out. This is a *stack overflow*. And usually leads to something like a segmentation fault or similar.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yea there is alot of check_for_loop in the call stack. t

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What am I supposed to do, it seems to the logic is correct

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So is my base case is at fault? I am looking for only the pairs where the previous loser can be a winner if there is no such case I'm indicating it by setting arr[arr_index] as -1

Comment: The logic might be correct, it's just that the limitations of the system doesn't allow it. Recursion is really just a fancy way to do a loop. You might be able to come up with a more iterative solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So if I were find a iterative solution it wouldn't cause the same error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used MAX*(MAX-1)/2 because pairs list is determined on compile time using another function this list is taken from an array of size [MAX][MAX]) All [i][i] values are always zero (there will be n such cases) and out of two pairs only one of either [i][j] or [j][i] will be taken (so no of possible pairs is halved) . Total no. (MAX^2) - [i][i] cases (MAX) / 2. Since I got stuck at this problem I thought I might isolate it and deal with it

Comment: You have infinite recursion, always calling `check_for_loop(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion "loop". For the example input, when `check_for_loop` is called for the second pair, i.e. `check_for_loop(0, 1)`, it will make a recursive call with the same arguments, and this will only stop when the process is out of stack memory.

The bug that is causing this infinite recursion is in `branches`, which I suppose is intended to list the nodes to which a given node connects. It has this erroneous statement:

```
            arr[arr_index] = pairs[i].winner;
```

...but `winner` is the node you already have. You need to collect the *target* node of the edge; which is `loser`.

So correct to:

```
            arr[arr_index] = pairs[i].loser;
```

Note that your algorithm is not efficient. Some hints:

- Create an adjacency list that is keyed by the node's index. This way you don't have to iterate *all* pairs only to find adjacent nodes for a given node.
- Instead of detecting edges that are not in a cycle, do the opposite: once you detect a cycle, you can immediately flag *all* edges that are on that cycle, and you don't have to do the work again for any of those, and can focus the rest of the algorithm to *other* edges only.

Comment: Yea this solved the problem. Thanks . Can please elaborate on your suggestion a little bit? What do you mean by adjacency list , is it an 2 dimensional array that contains all the possible branches for i th pair's loser as an array ? And by the second statement so you mean setting all nodes that has cycle to true and apply 'check_for_loop' only for the values that are set still false?

Comment: On both questions: yes.